# Weird colour effects in Unity build

Tags: unity, build

I have a project where I am getting a very weird thing in the build. Normally, the scene is working fine but some of the objects are showing like this. For example, the tracks or some of the trees.
[image]

Comment: It looks like the deeper mip levels of some textures have gotten stomped by unrelated memory. This could be an issue with your graphics driver. Does it occur on other computers?

Comment: yes this happening on other PCs.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Next thing to check would be your Unity installation. Can you uninstall and reinstall it fresh? Beyond that, we'll need a minimal complete verifiable example to help you debug this.

Comment: Currently the project is on unity 2018.3 and i am shifting it to 2018.4

Comment: If you're upgrading anyway, it might be worth making a backup and trying the latest LTS version. That will have the newest bug fixes, in case this is an engine bug that existed 3 years ago but has been fixed since then.

Comment: Are you using the built-in renderer or an SRP? You might also want to double-check your selected texture format, in case your textures are getting encoded to a format that the GPU doesn't like. Also, if you're using custom shaders, you might try substituting with a different shader in case it's a flaw in the shader.

Comment: @Kevin if there is an encoding issue then why it is running in the editor.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan I didn't know it was displaying correctly in the Editor because you didn't clearly state this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying Compression to some heavy texture. The problem has no more. I have applied normal compression to some of the heavy textures.